# Compile cython to other python version

Tags: python, cython

So I have some functions I wrote in cython to get a faster execution but they are all for python 3.11 and the project for which I need them is written in python 3.10 because some of the libraries aren't compatible with python 3.11. Is it possible to specify for which python version the .pyd file should be made? I am using the setup.py shown in the cython docs just with different file names:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='Hello world app',
    ext_modules=cythonize("hello.pyx"),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Comment: The easiest way is just to run setup.py with the Python version that you want to use. There probably are more advanced ways of doing it though

Comment: When i simply run the file it only produces the .c file but no .pyd file. This is the command I normally use in cmd python setup.py build_ext --inplace but it only makes the file for 3.11 and I can't specify the python version.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you run `python3.10 setup.py built_ext --inplace` instead

Comment: Doing this I get an error that python3.10 isn't recognized even though it's added to path system variables.